# Probability of same number

Tags: probability

what is the probability of a person with a last name “Doe” replacing a house vacated by another “Doe”. Assuming 1% of the population has last name “Doe”? I have a excel sheet where I have 50 most popular name in the US. Let's say "Doe" is the most popular name and 1% of the toal population have last name "Doe"? Let's assume "John" is the second most popular name and .8% of the population have last name "John". I want to know what is the probability of "Doe" replacing a house vacated by another "Doe"? Or "John" replacing a house vacated by another "John"? Thanks

Comment: _"1% of the population has same last name"_ Could you be more specific? Are there only 100 possible last names?

Comment: i have a excel sheet where i have the percentage of people who have the same last name. Let's say Doe is the most popular name and 1% of of the people have last name Doe. .5% of the population have the second most popular name and third most popular name is less than .5% of the population and so on

Comment: @LitonUddin: can you please update your question with those additional details as it is hard to decipher otherwise? Regards.

Comment: Please just edit your *one* question to make it as you desire instead of creating multiple, separate variations of the same question.

Comment: I have rolled back to the 3rd revision. Please do not remove the content that is relevant to this question only to repeat the question in a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a non-uniform distribution, then.  This means the result is more complicated than the uniform distribution implied by your initial statement.

Let

$p_{\text{name}}$ = probability of last name "name"

so that we have

$$\sum_{\text{name } \in \text{ Names}} p_{\text{name}} = 1$$

Then, the probability that the previous occupant had "name" *and* the current occupant also has "name" uses the rules for logical possibilities for *and* and *or*.  '

When looking for probabilities of A and B independent events, we have

$$P(A\text{ and }B) = P(A) P(B)$$

Similarly, for A or B disjoint, we have

$$P(A\text{ or }B) = P(A) + P(B)$$

What you want here is the probability of

previous has $\text{name}_1$ **and** current has $\text{name}_1$ **or**
previous has $\text{name}_2$ **and** current has $\text{name}_2$ **or**
...

which is written out:

$$P(\text{same last name}) = \sum_{\text{name } \in \text{ Names}} p_{\text{name}}^{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of last name $i$ is $p_i$, the probability that someone of last name $i$ is replaced by a match is $p_i$.  Summing over the last names that move out, the chance for any last name to be matched is $\sum_i p_i^2$

Comment: Could you please give an example of this ∑ i p 2 formula? I'm kind of new to statistics Thanks

Comment: @LitonUddin: If there were three last names, with abundances $0.6, 0.3, 0.1$, the probability of a replacement would be $0.6^2+0.3^2+0.1^2=0.36+0.09+0.01=0.46$

Comment: Sorry my question might be confusing. My question is basically,  what is the probability of a person with a last name “Doe” replacing a house vacated by another “Doe”. Assuming 1% of the population is “Doe”

Comment: For Doe specifically, if the vacator is known to be Doe, the chance is 1%.  If you don't know who left the house, it is $1\%^2=0.0001$, the first the chance that a Doe left, the second that a Doe arrived.  When you have two independent events, the probability of both happening is the product of the chances of each.  Similarly, flipping a coin twice you have $(\frac 12)^2=\frac 14$ chance of getting two heads.